# D3 Spinning Globe: trouble incorporating zoom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to incorporate a zoom function to Mike Bostock's spinning globe using D3. The zoom function works like a charm as long as the globe is spinning, or in 'animate' status. I however encounter the following issues:

(1) As soon as there is a mousedown even the zoom function is somehow disabled when I scroll the wheel, which is not a desired effect. I have narrowed down the issue, and I believe this behaviour occurs because of the following code on line 70: `done = true;`

(2) The zoom function has disabled all those interesting translation effects (e.g. gnomonic, equidistant, etc.) which is also not a desired effect.

I have a working fiddle that demonstrates the problems encountered: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/8sru2573/1/

Comment: *bump*. Anybody? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The animation is refreshing the drawing after you zoom.  When it's off you need to do this explicitly (I also cleaned up the zoom, it was throwing an error):

```
function move() {
    if(d3.event){
        var scale = d3.event.scale;
        var origin = [d3.event.translate[0] * -1, d3.event.translate[1]];

        projection.scale(scale);
        backgroundCircle.attr('r', scale);

        if (done) refresh(); //<-- explicit refresh  
    }
}
```

---

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sru2573/2/).

Comment: Mark, thank you so much. I am going through your code now to try to understand why your solution works :) Do you also know why the other projections have been disabled? That has also been keeping me barmy

Comment: @Noobster, the selection setting up the `.on` event is wrong.  Should be something like: `d3.select("#proj").on("change", function() { ...`  New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8sru2573/3/)

Comment: Thank you for this Mark. For some reason the transitions are now juddering to the point that they cannot be used. I am guessing I will need to disable them for now.